# Service running uncontrollably on IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

newbie developer

I have a restful wcf service. Usually I run it on iis express from visual studio express 2013. I can control it from iis express icon on the toolbar.

But last day i tested it via visual studio express 'local iis' option instead of iis Express (project -> properties -> web).

But after doing that, I have no control on the service. Even after restarting the system the service is still on. How can i control(stop) this service?

Comment: Why do you want to manually stop the service?  IIS will control starting and stopping it, by design.

Comment: i am just studying things. It was possible with iis express.

Comment: now i found out that there is a default web site that is running on iis manager. When i stop that i my 'localhost' itself goes down. Is there a way i can stop the service on a particular port?

Comment: The only way I can think of in IIS would be to create an application pool to run the service - you can stop individual application pools without stopping the entire default web site.